# Error read_html with R script in power BI

Tags: html, r, powerbi, rvest, scrape

I've made an R script to scrape a certain website. It works fine when I run it in Rstudio. Now I want to integrate it in a power Bi desktop so my co workers can work with it (without having to use Rstudio). However, I keep getting an error, it seems the read_html function doesnt work.

[image]

My original script, which works in Rstudio. I use a .xlsx file which contains a list of URLS (input.xlsx)

```
rm(list = ls())
library(rvest)
library(readxl)
library(xlsx)
library(rstudioapi)

# Set working directory and import URLs
setwd(dirname(getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
dfURL <- read_xlsx("Input.xlsx")

# Initiate dataframe
dfETA <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = nrow(dfURL)))
colnames(dfETA) <- c("URL", "Vessel", "Destination", "ETA")
dfETA$URL <- dfURL$URL

for (i in 1:nrow(dfURL)){
  # Get URL & load webpage
  url <- as.character(dfURL[i,])
  page <- read_html(url)
  
  # Extract CSS adresses
  CSSextract1 <- html_nodes(page,'.n3ata')
  CSSextract2 <- html_nodes(page,'.st')
  
  # Convert to text
  toText1 <- html_text(CSSextract1)
  toText2 <- html_text(CSSextract2)
  
  # Extract information from text
  destination <- trimws(toText1[1])
  ETA <- toText1[2]
  
  # Fill df with information
  dfETA$Vessel[i] <- toText2
  dfETA$Destination[i] <- destination
  dfETA$ETA[i] <- ETA
}
# Write to xlsx
write.xlsx(dfETA,"Output.xlsx", append = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

I already searched allot, one of the things I found is that you should point out the file and library locations explicitly. In power Bi, I made sure that the library locations are the same as the locations used by Rstudio (.libloc()) Also, prior to this error, Power Bi returned an error that it couldn't find the xml2 package, I installed and loaded it allong with the other packages, the resulting code is where I stand now and what produces the error. I've tried to make the code in such a way, that whoever is willing and able to help me can just copy and paste the code, so that the library locations are generic.

```
libloc_rvest <- find.package('rvest')
libloc_rvest <- substr(libloc_rvest,1,nchar(libloc_rvest) - nchar("rvest") - 1)
libloc_readxl <- find.package("readxl")
libloc_readxl <- substr(libloc_readxl,1,nchar(libloc_readxl) - nchar("readxl") - 1)
libloc_rstudioapi <- find.package("rstudioapi")
libloc_rstudioapi <- substr(libloc_rstudioapi,1,nchar(libloc_rstudioapi) - nchar("rstudioapi") - 1)
libloc_xml2 <- find.package("xml2")
libloc_xml2 <- substr(libloc_xml2,1,nchar(libloc_xml2) - nchar("xml2") - 1)
library(rvest, lib.loc=libloc_rvest)
library(readxl, lib.loc=libloc_readxl)
library(rstudioapi, lib.loc=libloc_rstudioapi)
library(xml2, lib.loc=libloc_xml2)

# Set working directory and import URLs
dfURL <- read_xlsx("N:/ETAscraper/ETAscraper/Input.xlsx")

# Initiate dataframe
dfETA <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = nrow(dfURL)))
colnames(dfETA) <- c("URL", "Vessel", "Destination", "ETA")
dfETA$URL <- dfURL$URL

for (i in 1:nrow(dfURL)){
  # Get URL & load webpage
  url <- as.character(dfURL[i,])
  page <- read_html(url)
  
  # Extract CSS adresses
  CSSextract1 <- html_nodes(page,'.n3ata')
  CSSextract2 <- html_nodes(page,'.st')
  
  # Convert to text
  toText1 <- html_text(CSSextract1)
  toText2 <- html_text(CSSextract2)
  
  # Extract information from text
  destination <- trimws(toText1[1])
  ETA <- toText1[2]
  
  # Fill df with information
  dfETA$Vessel[i] <- toText2
  dfETA$Destination[i] <- destination
  dfETA$ETA[i] <- ETA
}
# Write to xlsx
# write.xlsx(dfETA,"Output.xlsx", append = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

My input file looks as folows (just 1 column of URL's in a excel file)
[image]

If anyone could help me out, or point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Guessing something peculiar to your set-up as read_html worked for me when I just tried this: https://numidiabi.wordpress.com/2018/12/22/power-bi-r-web-scraping/ It points at where the R executables are rather than the packages. Packages are under ~/documents/R/win-library/4.0 on my system - the default download location.